# Codenameone native maps offline?

Tags: android, ios, maps, codenameone

it was brought to my attention that when I use the native maps in codenameone , and try to change the camera position the maps get blank , is there anyway that I could use the native maps functionality with no internet connection

```
final String HTML_API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer(HTML_API_KEY);
cnt.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(MarkerImg, false), new Coord(latitude, langitude), "", "", e3->{
});
Container root = LayeredLayout.encloseIn(
BorderLayout.center(cnt)
);
mapForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, root);
mapForm.revalidate();
```

---

Update :

The exception that I face on IOS when using the offline method :

```
MBTilesProvider provider = null;
        try{
            if ( MBTilesProvider.isLoaded("xxxxx.cn1tiles") ){
                provider = new MBTilesProvider("xxxxx.cn1tiles");
            } else {
                provider = MBTilesProvider.create("xxxxx.cn1tiles",fetchResourceFile().getData("xxxxx.cn1tiles"));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            new GlobalOperations().ShowDialog(null, "OffLine Map", "there was a problem with loading the map file "+e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ca_weblite_codename1_mapbox_MBTilesProvider.create:221
    at userclasses_StateMachine.beforeMap:5850
    at generated_StateMachineBase.beforeShow:5850
    at com_codename1_ui_util_UIBuilder.showForm:2518
    at com_codename1_ui_util_UIBuilder.showForm:2565
```

appreciate the help to make the map work with no internet connection

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Native Maps don't support offline functionality as far as I know although their app has some support for that. You can use this which doesn't offer the same level of UX as the native maps but works offline: https://github.com/shannah/CN1OfflineMaps

Comment: but that would be using `MapComponent` instead of `MapContainer` and I want to be able to use addMarker

Comment: never mind I checked `MapContainer` have a constructor that takes provider as an argument

Comment: The provider in map container only works for the simulator. It won't work for the device. You can look at the implementation of add marker in the native maps. It's pretty easy to implement it in `MapComponent`.

Comment: but what happens if I use on devices , I saw that it works offline , not like the old behavior that when you refresh the camera position the map get blank , I tried the map after a system reboot of the device and no wifi from the get-go

Comment: I have a problem when I put the code that loads the offline map in before show of the form that contains the map container I get null pointer exception on IOS , I will add the stacktrace from the ios sources in the question above

Comment: I suggest opening a different question for the iOS exception as someone else will need to answer that. Google just doesn't support native offline maps as far as I know. It makes sense as they charge based on cloud API usage